# output of list comprehension is different from data.append

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

The dataframe has transform_df.columns

```
Index(['MS SubClass', 'MS Zoning', 'Lot Area', 'Street', 'Lot Shape',
       'Land Contour', 'Utilities', 'Lot Config', 'Land Slope', 'Neighborhood',
       'Condition 1', 'Condition 2', 'Bldg Type', 'House Style',
       'Overall Qual', 'Overall Cond', 'Roof Style', 'Roof Matl',
       'Exterior 1st', 'Exterior 2nd', 'Mas Vnr Area', 'Exter Qual',
       'Exter Cond', 'Foundation', 'BsmtFin SF 1', 'BsmtFin SF 2',
       'Bsmt Unf SF', 'Total Bsmt SF', 'Heating', 'Heating QC', 'Central Air',
       '1st Flr SF', '2nd Flr SF', 'Low Qual Fin SF', 'Gr Liv Area',
       'Bsmt Full Bath', 'Bsmt Half Bath', 'Full Bath', 'Half Bath',
       'Bedroom AbvGr', 'Kitchen AbvGr', 'Kitchen Qual', 'TotRms AbvGrd',
       'Functional', 'Fireplaces', 'Garage Cars', 'Garage Area', 'Paved Drive',
       'Wood Deck SF', 'Open Porch SF', 'Enclosed Porch', '3Ssn Porch',
       'Screen Porch', 'Pool Area', 'Misc Val', 'Yr Sold', 'SalePrice',
       'Years Before Sale', 'Years Since Remod'],
      dtype='object')
```

and i have another list to check cols as

```
nominal_features = ["PID", "MS SubClass", "MS Zoning", "Street", "Alley", "Land Contour", "Lot Config", "Neighborhood", 
                    "Condition 1", "Condition 2", "Bldg Type", "House Style", "Roof Style", "Roof Matl", "Exterior 1st", 
                    "Exterior 2nd", "Mas Vnr Type", "Foundation", "Heating", "Central Air", "Garage Type", 
                    "Misc Feature", "Sale Type", "Sale Condition"]
```

When I do:

```
transform_cat_cols = [col for col in nominal_features if col in tranform_df.columns]
transform_cat_cols
it gives 
'PID',
 'MS Zoning',
 'Street',
 'Alley',
 'Land Contour',
 'Lot Config',
 'Neighborhood',
 'Condition 1',
 'Condition 2',
 'Bldg Type',
 'House Style',
 'Roof Style',
 'Roof Matl',
 'Exterior 1st',
 'Exterior 2nd',
 'Mas Vnr Type',
 'Foundation',
 'Heating',
 'Central Air',
 'Garage Type',
 'Misc Feature',
 'Sale Type',
 'Sale Condition']
```

these are same cols as in `nominal_features` list and many of these are not in the original `transform_df`. I know i am doing something wrong, but what?

Comment: I'm a little confused, this seems to be working? What is your expected result?

Comment: Typo: tranform_df or is there a different dataframe with and without an 's'? Also, could you use sets, and just get the common values with '&'? I'm not sure if it works on transform_df.columns but it should. Like this: transform_cat_cols=list(set(tranform_df.columns)&set(nominal_features))

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a subtle problem with your script because on my side, your logic, works perfectly.  I would have written this as a comment but I need to show you the code.  Anyway, check your variables and dataframe names.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['MS SubClass', 'MS Zoning', 'Lot Area', 'Street', 'Lot Shape',
       'Land Contour', 'Utilities', 'Lot Config', 'Land Slope', 'Neighborhood',
       'Condition 1', 'Condition 2', 'Bldg Type', 'House Style',
       'Overall Qual', 'Overall Cond', 'Roof Style', 'Roof Matl',
       'Exterior 1st', 'Exterior 2nd', 'Mas Vnr Area', 'Exter Qual',
       'Exter Cond', 'Foundation', 'BsmtFin SF 1', 'BsmtFin SF 2',
       'Bsmt Unf SF', 'Total Bsmt SF', 'Heating', 'Heating QC', 'Central Air',
       '1st Flr SF', '2nd Flr SF', 'Low Qual Fin SF', 'Gr Liv Area',
       'Bsmt Full Bath', 'Bsmt Half Bath', 'Full Bath', 'Half Bath',
       'Bedroom AbvGr', 'Kitchen AbvGr', 'Kitchen Qual', 'TotRms AbvGrd',
       'Functional', 'Fireplaces', 'Garage Cars', 'Garage Area', 'Paved Drive',
       'Wood Deck SF', 'Open Porch SF', 'Enclosed Porch', '3Ssn Porch',
       'Screen Porch', 'Pool Area', 'Misc Val', 'Yr Sold', 'SalePrice',
       'Years Before Sale', 'Years Since Remod'])
nominal_features = ["PID", "MS SubClass", "MS Zoning", "Street", "Alley", "Land Contour", "Lot Config", "Neighborhood", 
                    "Condition 1", "Condition 2", "Bldg Type", "House Style", "Roof Style", "Roof Matl", "Exterior 1st", 
                    "Exterior 2nd", "Mas Vnr Type", "Foundation", "Heating", "Central Air", "Garage Type", 
                    "Misc Feature", "Sale Type", "Sale Condition"]

transform_cat_cols = [col for col in nominal_features if col in df.columns]
print(transform_cat_cols)

['MS SubClass', 'MS Zoning', 'Street', 'Land Contour', 'Lot Config', 'Neighborhood', 'Condition 1', 'Condition 2', 'Bldg Type', 'House Style', 'Roof Style', 'Roof Matl', 'Exterior 1st', 'Exterior 2nd', 'Foundation', 'Heating', 'Central Air']
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the details. What i am looking for is that the final transform_cat_cols should only have cols from that match from df datafrme. that said, your output also has more cols than transform_cat_cols, this is the same issue I am facing.

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake in pasting the results.  I corrected it.